# Getting weird, process.php hits on my rails based site. What is this an indication of?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

I was looking in my google analytics and discovered a few php hits to pages that, as a rails site obviously not apart of it. Here's an example:

```
/process.php?d=WnCeik5EGhC5sO5YToPnII5eaQ==&b=1
```

There's quite of few of them. Are these hijack attempts or attacks. If so how do I stop them?

Comment: It could be a malicious trawler, or it could be innocent. How long have you had the domain? A previous owner might have had a process.php URL to which this would be possibly legitimate traffic.

Comment: You can check further, check secondary dimensions for user agent, location, etc. This info should give you some insight to how likely this is to be legitimate.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins The site is brand new in the sense I just started doing promo for it. I've had the domain for a while.

Comment: These look like landscaping or hack attempts. If you are delivering a 404 error for these pages, I would not worry about it. These things happen. Make sure your software is up to date and any code you have written is secure and let it go.

Comment: We can't tell you more about this without knowing if this is part of your site.  As closetnoc says, if you are returning 404 there should be nothing to worry about.